# Code block in coroutine using "Dispatchers.Main" not being run

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

I've searched everywhere and I haven't found anything that seems to be a solution to my problem

I have a function using coroutines:

```
fun onAuthenticated() {
    launch (Dispatchers.IO) {
        userRepo.retrieveSelf()!!.let { name ->
            userRepo.addAuthenticatedAccount(name)
            userRepo.setCurrentAccount(name)
        }

        activity?.setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, Intent())

        // this block doesn't seem to be run
        withContext(Dispatchers.Main) {
            Log.d(TAG, "ok looks gucci")
            activity?.finish()
        }
    }
}
```

When this function is called, the code in the `withContext(Dispatchers.Main) { ... }` block doesn't run. I'm using it to access the activity in the main thread.

I've been getting kind of frustrated and I'm not sure if I don't understand how the dispatcher/coroutine is supposed to work or there's something I'm missing.

Let me know if you need any additional details or code!

***EDIT***
So Marko was right. After I moved the `activity.?.setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, Intent())` so that it was being run with the main dispatcher, I found out there was another part of the code in `userRepo.setCurrentAccount(name)` that was giving an issue. After updating the code as seen below, it works as expected!

```
override fun onAuthenticated() {
    val handler = CoroutineExceptionHandler { _, e ->
        Snackbar.make(
            web_auth_rootview,
                "Authentication unsuccessful",
                Snackbar.LENGTH_INDEFINITE
            ).show()
    }

    launch(Dispatchers.Main + handler) {
        userRepo.retrieveSelf()!!.let { name ->
            userRepo.addAuthenticatedAccount(name)
            userRepo.setCurrentAccount(name)
        }

        activity?.apply {
            setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, Intent())
            onBackPressed()
        }
    }
}
```

Big Thanks to Marko for helping me out!

Comment: Are you sure you are not getting an exception somewhere above?

Comment: @Kuno I'm still at school right now but I'll check when I get home and provide an update :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
activity?.setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, Intent())
```

Here you try to touch a GUI component from the IO thread. This probably throws an exception, but since it's on the IO thread, nothing catches it.

You can wrap everything in a try-catch, but your program would automatically work better if you used the proper idiom, which is to `launch` in the `Main` dispatcher and only switch to the IO context for the blocking operations:

```
launch(Dispatchers.Main) {
    withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
        userRepo.retrieveSelf()!!.let { name ->
            userRepo.addAuthenticatedAccount(name)
            userRepo.setCurrentAccount(name)
        }
    }
    activity?.setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, Intent())
    Log.d(TAG, "ok looks gucci")
    activity?.finish()
}
```

Now, if you get an exception in the IO dispatcher, it will propagate to the top-level coroutine, which will cause an exception on the main thread, and your application will crash with it. This is a solid foundation to add your error handling logic on top of.

Of course, this is still not the way you should work with coroutines because you're missing the structured concurrency aspect.

Comment: That makes alot of sense! I'm at school right now but I'll try it when I get home and update the result later. I just realized that I didn't need to launch the ```userRepo``` methods with IO dispatcher here when you pointed it out since all they are already launched with IO dispatchers locally.

Comment: Alright so I made some modifications and it works as expected now. I'll post the changes below if anyone stumbles across them in the future